# Interpreting AIC and BIC fit

Tags: psychometrics, aic, structural-equation-modeling, bic, confirmatory-factor

I'm writing a CFA paper, and I have run into some trouble interpreting the AIC and BIC. This is my first paper using continuous variables, thus the first time I will be reporting these fit statistics and I'm still learning the SEM method overall so bear with me, please.

The paper in question looks at an existing psychometric, but I am scoring it in a slightly different way than was intended. The measure has a frequency of experience and a distress element in it, and usually the frequency of experience is analysed for best fitting model with the distress element later correlated with the model. I have summed both of these elements (frequency scores + distress scores) to produce a new single set of scores which I have then run within a CFA framework (5 factor model using MLR).

The other fit indices look great, however, the AIC and BIC look like this:

CFA on the different elements of the measure:

```
Frequency : AIC= 12313.226 BiC: 12602.260
Distress  : AIC= 10318.698 BIC: 10607.731
Summed    : AIC= 22039.130 BIC: 22328.163
```

How would I go about interpreting these values?

Comment: Can you please clarify exactly what your question is? You seem to be indicating there is something wrong with your AIC/BIC values but I'm not sure what you're referring to.

Comment: Are you referring to the magnitude of the absolute values? ICs should not be interpreted on an absolute scale. All seems to be in order

Comment: I was talking with a collegue today and showed him the results, he mentioned that the lowest AIC and BIC was a preferable model and by summing the Freq+Distress elements of the measure may have done something as the AIC and BIC looks quite large. To clarify it is the Summed scores I wish to use the AIC and BIC fit statistics look very large when compared to the freq and distress.

Comment: As Momo said, the magnitude of an AIC/BIC value should not be interpreted on its own - only AIC/BIC values relative to each other.

Comment: I guess I have quite a bit to learn yet - I was interpreting the ICs above as a group thus thought the Summed ICs were too high. Okay, seem I need to break out some books. Thanks guys for your input this far.

kind regards,

Comment: @Macro Given that, would it be correct to interpret the above ICs as indicating worse fit in the Summed model?  I'm not familiar with this context and I'm a little unsure of what exactly is happening in the models, but the real question seems to be "What are these ICs telling me about my combined measure?"

Comment: @Matt - YES! That is what I was trying to say. Thank you.

Comment: You are right. The smaller the value the "better" the fit relative to the other models. Hence Distress better rhan Frequency better than Summed.

Comment: @matt was who I meant specifically. But Macro's usually right too ;)

Comment: @Rave So a good next question might be about the specifics of combining scores as you've done - summing them might not work, but perhaps there are other ways.

Comment: @Matt - yes you could be right, summing the two elements may not work but all the other fit indices fit perfectly except the ICs on the summed scores. I don't understand why summing two scores from the same psychometric would produce ICs like these. Granted the distress element is usually collapsed to one variable and correlated later in many papers but we think there is a strong rationale for what we are doing - I just need to know why the ICs are behaving like this.

Anyways, Ill let my professor work this one out!

Comment: I'm not sure I follow all of this but the summed and non-summed AICs are on different scales (since the likelihood scales with the sample size, which is different in the summed and non-summed groups), so you can't compare them directly. You can only compare them when the data set remains fixed (so the likelihoods are on the same scale).

Answer (score 2):

You can check out this book: "[Model Selection and Multimodel Inference A Practical Information-Theoretic Approach](http://books.google.ca/books?id=BQYR6js0CC8C&printsec=frontcover&dq=Model%20Selection%20and%20Multimodel%20Inference&source=bl&ots=i96Wodnf_C&sig=M8GYu7Zi8FNf0PfWN24qL0rGymY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=qXkoUPv5A-rX0QHx_oDgDA&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Model%20Selection%20and%20Multimodel%20Inference&f=false)", Burnham & Anderson 2nd. Ed.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @user13138. Can you say more about this book & why it will address the OP's question?

Comment: As Macro said, Section 2.11.1 explains that when the data sets are different, you cannot compare the AIC's. I think that is the reason why the criteria for the summed model are significantly different. Gung, don’t you think the one who asked the question should do a little bit of research him/herself?